# What is the meaning of "shoot the average"?

Tags: phrases

Could someone explain the meaning of "shoot the average" in the context below?

> I didn't change the median age of the group that much, but I think I really shot the average.

Edit: This came from the book "Unix: A History and a Memoir", and it's a part of email (paraphrased) from the Ken Thompson who were asked for confirmation about his move from one company to another. He was 63 years old at the time.

I couldn't find it on any dictionary or via web search, so I guess it's quite colloquial usage.

Thank you.

Comment: "Shoot" as in golf/pool/basketball.

Comment: Shot must mean ruined (changed badly). My age can move the median (midpoint) by one, at most. But if my age averages into a small group and is very different from the current average, it can really ruin some desired previous average.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I'm pretty sure you're wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks What would it mean to "'shoot' as in golf" the average? The only meaning I can think of is that the speaker literally played a sport and their performance was average. But that doesn't make sense in this context, because the word "but" indicates that the meaning of the second part contrasts with the first part.

Comment: To me "shot" in this context of age, obviously means ruined as Yosef above says. The group could have been categorised as being something (young probably) except for the one person who messed up that description by being too old (probably)

Comment: The main problem is that there is not enough context.

Comment: He didn't change the median age but instead ranked as average.  Note that if he didn't change the median then it would have been very unlikely for him to radically alter the average.

Comment: 'The average' should probably be 'the mean'; a single extreme value can affect the mean of a group of data significantly, but rarely the median. It is poor choice of  language to use 'average' for 'mean' when different types of average are being compared. // 'Shot' can only logically mean 'ruined' here, as Yosef says. Though I'm used to 'This tyre is shot', using the verb non-adjectivally in this sense is new to me.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. @Greybeard, I've edited to provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

I think the author is saying they were significantly younger or older than the rest of their group.

The appropriate definition from [Collins](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shot) is:

> no longer working or effective:
>   "It's no good - these gears are shot."

That is, the author was so much younger (or older) than the rest of the group that they "broke" the average (but not the median, so they must mean "mean").

Comment: It’s like being a a room when Jeff Bezos walks in. The average wealth goes up. The median wealth shifts from the previous median wealth to the wealth of the next most wealthy, probably some other ordinary Joe.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. On dictionary, that definition is classified as adjective. Would it be best to see this as somewhat ungrammatical use in informal email exchange?

Comment: @Felipe1979 the author's use is grammatically sound, but the sentence is clumsy. It’s more normal to use "shot" as an adjective in this context, but I don’t think the author has considered that. I think the author has used a verb here so he can sort of claim responsibility for the average being shot (ruined).